# Numpy - Count Number of Values Until Condition Is Satisfied

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have two numpy arrays of the same size.

```
ArrayOne = np.array([ 2, 5, 5, 6, 7, 10, 13])

ArrayTwo = np.array([ 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 24])
```

How can I count how many elements there are until the beginning of the array. Unless the condition ArrayOne >= ArrayTwo is satisfied. In which case how many elements until that condition. Then make an array out of the result.

So as an example for element [0] there are 0 elements in front. For element [1] there is 1 element in front, and ArrayOne >= ArrayTwo wasn't satisfied. At element [5] in ArrayOne is bigger than element[0] in ArrayTwo so there are four elements until element [1] in ArrayTwo Etc.
Giving the result

```
result = np.array([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ArrayOne and ArrayTwo have different sizes in your example.

Comment: This is very hard to follow. I'm still unclear on how you got to the values in the array `result`.

Comment: To answer, thanks for pointing out the arrays were different sizes (it's fixed). I tried my best to formulate the question, maybe I can formulate it better in the morning.

Comment: If your arrays are sorted, something like `np.arange(ArrayOne.size) - ArrayTwo.searchsorted(ArrayOne)`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, at index i you have the value

```
value = i -count(how often element i in array one was bigger than array two until index i)
```

Because I'm on mobile with damn autocorrect, I rename the two arrays to a and b.

```
def get_value(a, b, i):
    max_value = a[i]
    nb_smaller_elements = sum(1 for el in range(i) if b[el] < max_value)
    return i - nb_smaller_elements
```

Comment: What about `sum(b[el] < max_value for el in range(i))`

Answer (score -1):

I think I got it. Using @Paul Panzer 's answer, I made a for loop that goes through the list.

```
def toggle(ArrayOne,ArrayTwo):
    a = 0
    sum = -1
    linels = []
    for i in range(len(ArrayOne)):
        sum += 1
        a = sum - np.searchsorted(ArrayTwo, ArrayOne[i])
        linels.append(a)
    return np.array(linels)
```

I get the result

```
linels = np.array([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3])
```